# How to implement nested collectionview in Marionette?

Tags: marionette

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/walkingp/me4NK/476/) my fiddle, it's my first time to use Marionette.

I want to generate HTML like this:

```
<h2>Class 1</h2>
<div class="sts">
<table>
<tr>
...
</tr>
</table>
</div >

<h2>Class 2</h2>
<div class="sts">
<table>
<tr>
...
</tr>
</table>
</div >
```

Comment: In ver 1.* you may need `'itemViewContainer: 'tbody'` in `CompositeView` to enclose `itemView`.  If you use ver 2.*, check doc.

Comment: Your `appendHTML` method is no longer needed.  Look at the latest marionette source code in your fiddle.  Overwrite attachHtml instead.